# how to fix my PHP code or google ads to appear ads between the lines that looped from db

Tags: php, html, mysqli, ads

I have a site and google approved my ads account. My site has rows looped from DB. I want to put every row of the Goo ads inside the `fieldset` tag

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<fieldset>
my row here
</fieldset>";

}
```

for example:

```
<fieldset1>
my row here from DB
<endfieldset1> 

<fieldset2>
GOOGLE ADS 
<endfieldset2>

<fieldset3>
my row here from DB
<endfieldset3>

 <fieldset4>
my row here from DB
<endfieldset4>
```

Comment: Show us your actual code, not pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a stupid solution but it might work for what you want tbh.

```
<?php

    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        // Echo your normal stuff here

        if ($counter == 5) {
            // Echo your add here and reset the counter
            $counter = 0;
        }

        $counter++;

    }

?>
```

So once the counter reacher 5 display your add and reset it to 0